# Optimizing Dijkstra for fixed number of weights

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

Let G=(V,E) be our directed graph with edgeweigths
c:E->Q≥0.
Now modifiy Dijkstra's algorithm, such that the algorithm solves instances with only a constant number of unique edge weights in linear time. In other words, if |{c_e | e∈E}| =: C is independent of |V| and |E|, the runtime of Dijkstra's algorithm can be improved.

Can anyone help me with that problem?

I don't know where to start :)

Comment: I think you need bounded edge weights, not just a bounded number of edge weights.  That implies a bounded number of relevant priorities and lets you replace the priority queue with a circular array of lists.